# hyperlink to jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have our accordion tabs ( horizontal as follows )

```
<ul class="tabs"> 
    <li><a href="#tab1"><span class="upArrow">Inbox (2)</span></a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tab2"><span class="downArrow">Sent (8)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3"><span class="composeMssg">Compose</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

We have the tab titles as such

```
<div class="tab_content_container"> 

    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content" style="font-size: 12px;">
```

Content and then closing divs, and remainder of tabs linking to the href's as you do.

Issue is ,

How can I link to #tab2 from external link and open that tab on page load.

Comment: ?? navigate to other page or load content from other page? or set default #tab2

Comment: Sorry, no we wish to navigate from another page to the page with the tabs on and open the specific tab we want to ie. tab3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to select a particular tab via an external link, then you need to do..

```
$("#tabs").tabs("select", "#tabid");
```

So, for selecting `tab2` on page load..

```
$(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", "#tab2");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a script tag in the body tag of your html.

```
$("#tab2").hide()
$("#tab3").hide()
$("#tab1").show()
```